# динамические массивы - как передать из функции в main?

Tags: c++, функции, динамические-массивы

Доброго времени суток. Возник вопрос - а в принципе возможно ли передать созданный в функции динамический массив в основную программу? И если возможно, как это сделать, например, в следующем коде:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<windows.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<iomanip>

using namespace std;

void SeparateArr(int *arr, int size);


void main()
{
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    srand(time(NULL));

    const int Size = 10;
    int mas[Size] = {0,1,-2,0,3,-4,0,5,-6,7};

    SeparateArr(mas, Size);

    _getch();
}

void SeparateArr(int *arr, int size) {
    int kneg = 0, kzer = 0, kpos = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (arr[i] < 0) kneg++;
        if (arr[i] == 0) kzer++;
        if (arr[i] > 0) kpos++;
    }
    int *arneg = new int[kneg];
    int *arzer = new int[kzer];
    int *arpos = new int[kpos];

    int kn0 = 0, kz0 = 0, kp0 = 0;

    if(arneg !=0 && arzer !=0 && arpos !=0){
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            if (arr[i] < 0) { arneg[kn0] = arr[i]; kn0++; }
            if (arr[i] == 0) { arzer[kz0] = arr[i]; kz0++; }
            if (arr[i] > 0) { arpos[kp0] = arr[i]; kp0++; }
        }
    }
    else cout << "Error!";

    cout << "\nМассив отрицательных чисел:\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < kneg; i++) cout << setw(4) << arneg[i];
    cout << "\nМассив нулей:\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < kzer; i++) cout << setw(4) << arzer[i];
    cout << "\nМассив положительных чисел:\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < kpos; i++) cout << setw(4) << arpos[i];

    delete[]arneg;
    arneg = 0;
    delete[]arzer;
    arzer = 0;
    delete[]arpos;
    arpos = 0;
}
```

Comment: Конечно, можно, если вернуть указатель. А делетирование выделите в отдельную функцию, ее можно вызвать, когда массив будет не нужен.

Comment: а можно поставить аргументом функции еще не инициализированный динамический массив?

Comment: Я как раз пытаюсь дать ответ. Суть в том, чтобы вернуть массив из 3 указателей на созданные вами массивы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не понимаю, в чем проблема?..

```
int * makeArray(size_t size)
{
    return new int[size];
}

int main()
{
    int * array = makeArray(10);

    // Работаем с массивом array[10]

    delete[] array;
}
```

Или я неверно истолковал вопрос?

**Update**

Ну вот, [смотрите вашу задачу](https://ideone.com/m3leuI):

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

void distrib(int * src, size_t count,
             int** p, size_t*pn,
             int** n, size_t*nn,
             int** z, size_t*zn)
{
    *p = new int[count];
    *n = new int[count];
    *z = new int[count];
    *pn = *nn = *zn = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {
        if (src[i] < 0)      (*n)[(*nn)++] = src[i];
        else if (src[i] > 0) (*p)[(*pn)++] = src[i];
        else (*z)[(*zn)++] = src[i]; // Глупо, мы и так знаем, что нули...
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int m[40];
    for(int i = 0; i < 40; ++i)
        m[i] = rand()%7 - 3;

    int *p, *n, *z;
    size_t pn, nn, zn;
    distrib(m,40,&p,&pn,&n,&nn,&z,&zn);

    cout << "Pos:  ";
    for(int i = 0; i < pn; ++i) cout << p[i] << " "; cout << endl;
    cout << "Neg:  ";
    for(int i = 0; i < nn; ++i) cout << n[i] << " "; cout << endl;
    cout << "Zero:  ";
    for(int i = 0; i < zn; ++i) cout << z[i] << " "; cout << endl;

}
```

Comment: Верните 3 массива. Хотя это можно сделать, положив их в массив или стркуктуру.

Comment: @HasmikGaryaka Так это вопрос или ответ? :)

Comment: проблема в том, что только разбираюсь в теме указателей и еще не совсем понимаю синтаксис. Спасибо за ваш ответ, сейчас буду экспериментировать. Хотя - по условиям задачи нужно вернуть 3 массива, вот текст: _Задание 7:
Написать функцию, которая получает указатель на статический массив и его размер. Функция распределяет положительные, отрицательные и нулевые элементы в отдельные динамические массивы._

Comment: См. обновленный ответ

Comment: хотел бы убедиться, что я правильно понимаю код типа (*n)[(*nn)++] = src[i]; -  указатель на массив негативных [указатель на индекс негативных, который ЗАТЕМ сдвигаем на +1]? То есть постфиксная форма прибавляет +1 уже ПОСЛЕ операции присваивания значения?

Comment: И, насколько понимаю, нужно еще обнулить массивы?

Comment: @Venrici В данном случае это не обязательно: поскольку я беру их с запасом, я кроме самих массивов возвращаю и количество элементов в них, а потому мы знаем, где лежит нужная информация, а где - просто мусор. В выражении `(*n)[(*nn)++] = src[i];` - да: берем массив `*n` (`n` - указатель на массив, или, что то же, указатель на указатель на первый элемент), его элементу номер `*nn` (`nn` - указатель на переменную `int`, в которой храним количество записанных в массив элементов) присваиваем `src[i]`, после чего увеличиваем эту переменную, так, чтобы она содержала количество элементов в массиве.

Answer (score 1):

Вернуть массив, в котором лежат все 3 массива

```
int ** SeparateArr(int *arr, int size) {
        int *arneg = new int[kneg];
        int *arzer = new int[kzer];
        int *arpos = new int[kpos];
    int * x[3]=new int*[3];
    x[0]=arneg; x[1]=arzer;x[2]=arpos;
    return x;
    }
```

Comment: Не проще ли через указатели?

Comment: Дело вкуса.  )))

Comment: Да, он локальный, но указатель на первый копируется в return.

Comment: @HasmikGaryaka, пришел к выводу, что это я напутал, скорее всего, и уже стёр комментарий.

Comment: @HasmikGaryaka, у вас там, где `x[3]` русская `х` вместо "икс". Потом gcc выдает предупреждение: `warning: address of local variable ‘x’ returned [-Wreturn-local-addr]`, то есть, может быть, так действительно делать нельзя.

Comment: @Harry, код вообще правильный?

Comment: Адрес массива, который выделен динамически. А увеличив этот адрес, получим адрес второго массива. Ну в принципе можно и x динамически выделить.

Comment: @HasmikGaryaka, исправьте в пятой строке на `int ** x=new int*[3];`, а то вы сначала выделяете локальный массив, а потом пытаетесь его заменить выделенным через `new`.

Comment: @AlexanderZonov Ну... в данном случае я, как в анекдоте, выступил в роли стратега, а не тактика :)

Answer (score 0):

Я все же немного исправлю [код @HasmikGaryaka](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/728240/239133). Возвращать массив нельзя, а структуру, содержащую массив, можно:

```
struct int3 {
    int *array[3];
};

int3 SeparateArr(int *arr, int size) {
    int *arneg = new int[100];
    int *arzer = new int[100];
    int *arpos = new int[100];
    int3 x = {arneg, arzer,arpos};
    return x;
}
```

Comment: Массив, память под который выделена через new, можно возвращать (т.е. в текущем варианте ответа там сейчас правильно). Нельзя возвращать массивы, объявленные в локальных переменных.

Comment: @insolor, предполагаю, что тут дело не в выделении памяти, а в том, как массив синтаксически выглядит для компилятора. У меня GCC страшно ругается и на исправленный @HasmikGaryaka код. Потом, если вы объявляете именно обычный массив, то память под него резервируется в стеке. Не понимаю, как ее можно выделить через `new`?

Comment: Да, правильно, там не `int * x[3]` должно быть с левой стороны, а двойной указатель `int ** x`.

Comment: Почему можно возвращать указатель на массив интов(динамический), а нельзя возвращать аналогичный указатель на массив массивов?

Comment: @HasmikGaryaka, как я понял, можно. Но конструкция `inr *x[3]` уже выделяет массив указателей в стеке функции. После `return` этот массив может быть затерт другими данными, поскольку стека функции больше нет, ведь она завершилась.

Comment: int * makeArray()
{
    int *x=new int[3];
    return x;
}
вы согласны, что так делать можно? Ведь x локальная переменная, но return ее копирует.

Comment: Не затрется, если через new выделен.

Comment: @HasmikGaryaka, вроде, да, так можно.